# How to only present output in Google Colaboratory?

Tags: svg, google-colaboratory

I have the following svg that presents a logo but I want to generate a **.pdf** where it's only present the logo and not the code of this specific cell, how can I do that?

The svg:

```
%%html
<svg width="529" height="265" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:undefined="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape">
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <metadata id="svg_14">image/svg+xml</metadata>
  <g>
   <metadata id="svg_9">image/svg+xml</metadata>
   <g transform="matrix(1.33333 0 0 -1.33333 0 468.32)"   id="svg_2">
    <g transform="translate(0 -76.2875) scale(0.1 0.1)" id="svg_3">
     <!-- uminho symbol + red background -->
     <path fill-rule="nonzero" fill="#a42a3c" id="svg_7" d="m0,2291.02528l1984.25,0l0,1984.25l-1984.25,0l0,-1984.25"/>
     <!-- uminho symbol -->
     <path fill-rule="nonzero" fill="#ffffff" id="svg_6" d="m1502.43,3514.55528l-378.95,-220.62c-68.8,-39.71 -129.285,64.76 -60.48,104.49l379,220.52c68.88,39.76 129.16,-64.71 60.43,-104.39m-1039.617,-1.46l383.14,-217.25c68.711,-39.66 129.059,64.89 60.172,104.67l-383.203,217.16c-68.77,39.7 -128.938,-64.84 -60.109,-104.58m459.449,-797.92l-0.047,440.75c0,33.37 27.109,60.33 60.379,60.33c33.336,0 60.336,-27.01 60.336,-60.34l-0.05,-440.74c0,-33.28 -26.92,-60.34 -60.286,-60.33c-33.321,0 -60.332,27.01 -60.332,60.33m-379.258,235.44l184.039,104.36c68.863,39.77 8.461,144.3 -60.289,104.6l-183.996,-104.46c-68.774,-39.72 -8.574,-144.24 60.246,-104.5m918.046,-3.45l-179.19,108.08c-68.78,39.7 -8.28,144.18 60.55,104.43l179.14,-108.16c68.72,-39.67 8.4,-144.12 -60.5,-104.35m-478.495,964.28c-33.371,0 -60.293,-27.05 -60.293,-60.33l-0.047,-211.59c0,-33.32 27.012,-60.34 60.34,-60.34c33.265,0 60.375,26.98 60.375,60.34l-0.05,211.59c0,33.32 -27,60.33 -60.325,60.33"/>
     <!-- ec symbol + blue background -->
     <path fill-rule="nonzero" fill="#8cbce8" id="svg_5" d="m1984.25,2291.02528l1984.26,0l0,1984.25l-1984.26,0l0,-1984.25"/>
     <!-- ec symbol -->
     <path fill-rule="nonzero" fill="#ffffff" id="svg_4" d="m3540.85,3037.67528l-100.97,183.1c-39.72,68.79 -144.26,8.6 -104.58,-60.12l101.07,-183.06c39.74,-68.84 144.12,-8.57 104.48,60.08m-17.75,558.93c0,33.34 -27.02,60.24 -60.29,60.24l-211.41,0.05c-33.3,0 -60.28,-27 -60.28,-60.29c0,-33.25 26.94,-60.34 60.28,-60.34l211.41,0.05c33.31,0 60.29,26.99 60.29,60.29m-362.52,-738.96c16.65,28.85 6.78,65.71 -22.07,82.36c-28.87,16.67 -65.68,6.72 -82.31,-22.09l-105.75,-183.06c-16.65,-28.84 -6.77,-65.71 22.07,-82.36c28.79,-16.62 65.73,-6.83 82.4,22.04l105.66,183.11zm-150.24,974.55c16.66,28.85 6.77,65.71 -22.06,82.36c-28.88,16.67 -65.69,6.72 -82.32,-22.09l-105.75,-183.06c-16.65,-28.84 -6.76,-65.71 22.07,-82.36c28.8,-16.62 65.73,-6.83 82.4,22.05l105.66,183.1zm-241.49,-862.5c0,33.25 -26.96,60.34 -60.29,60.34l-211.42,-0.05c-33.29,0 -60.29,-27 -60.29,-60.29c-0.01,-33.35 27.04,-60.24 60.29,-60.24l211.4,-0.05c33.31,0 60.31,26.99 60.31,60.29m-146.85,428.75l-105.75,183.06c-16.63,28.81 -53.44,38.76 -82.31,22.09c-28.84,-16.65 -38.72,-53.51 -22.07,-82.36l105.66,-183.1c16.67,-28.88 53.61,-38.67 82.4,-22.05c28.83,16.65 38.72,53.52 22.07,82.36"/>
    </g>
   </g>
  </g>
 </g>
</svg>
```

The Output is this one:
[image]
Thanks in advance.

**R.:** One of the options I have is convert the svg to a png and put it there but I would like to not do that extra step.

Answer (score 1):

By far the simplest way to convert SVG to PDF is via HTML, so I suggest you add enough HTML wrapping to control the output. Here we can see the normal HTML placement would include lots of other page data which of course you may add as you wish. One gotcha is of course units so you may need to introduce scaling factors but that is way beyond this simple demonstration of how to show and convert SVG-to-PDF

[image]

The first step is wrapping the SVG with the HTML (and this is overkill) but I simply used your Minimal !! SVG for cut and paste in a template as proof of concept.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<!-- saved from url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70731953 -->
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>None</title>


<meta name="GENERATOR" content="KJs Template Builder V 2022-01">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css"><style>
@media print {
  @page {
    /* For different margins – use the standard CSS margin property: north, east, south, west, here it is one value */
    margin: 0;

    /* Browser default, customisable by the user if using the print dialogue. */
    size: auto;

    /* Default, In my instance of Edge, this is a vertical or horizontal A4 format, but you might find something different depending on your locale. */
    size: portrait;

    /* Different width and height. here using stated width="529" height="265" can be px or pt or cm. For square, just use one value or use name like A6 landscape; note this is over-riding both above size: */
    size: 529px 265px;
  }
  body { margin: 0; }
}
</style>
</head><body bgcolor="white" text="black" link="blue" vlink="purple" alink="red">


<svg width="529" height="265" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:undefined="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape">
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <metadata id="svg_14">image/svg+xml</metadata>
  <g>
   <metadata id="svg_9">image/svg+xml</metadata>
   <g transform="matrix(1.33333 0 0 -1.33333 0 468.32)"   id="svg_2">
    <g transform="translate(0 -76.2875) scale(0.1 0.1)" id="svg_3">
     <!-- uminho symbol + red background -->
     <path fill-rule="nonzero" fill="#a42a3c" id="svg_7" d="m0,2291.02528l1984.25,0l0,1984.25l-1984.25,0l0,-1984.25"/>
     <!-- uminho symbol -->
     <path fill-rule="nonzero" fill="#ffffff" id="svg_6" d="m1502.43,3514.55528l-378.95,-220.62c-68.8,-39.71 -129.285,64.76 -60.48,104.49l379,220.52c68.88,39.76 129.16,-64.71 60.43,-104.39m-1039.617,-1.46l383.14,-217.25c68.711,-39.66 129.059,64.89 60.172,104.67l-383.203,217.16c-68.77,39.7 -128.938,-64.84 -60.109,-104.58m459.449,-797.92l-0.047,440.75c0,33.37 27.109,60.33 60.379,60.33c33.336,0 60.336,-27.01 60.336,-60.34l-0.05,-440.74c0,-33.28 -26.92,-60.34 -60.286,-60.33c-33.321,0 -60.332,27.01 -60.332,60.33m-379.258,235.44l184.039,104.36c68.863,39.77 8.461,144.3 -60.289,104.6l-183.996,-104.46c-68.774,-39.72 -8.574,-144.24 60.246,-104.5m918.046,-3.45l-179.19,108.08c-68.78,39.7 -8.28,144.18 60.55,104.43l179.14,-108.16c68.72,-39.67 8.4,-144.12 -60.5,-104.35m-478.495,964.28c-33.371,0 -60.293,-27.05 -60.293,-60.33l-0.047,-211.59c0,-33.32 27.012,-60.34 60.34,-60.34c33.265,0 60.375,26.98 60.375,60.34l-0.05,211.59c0,33.32 -27,60.33 -60.325,60.33"/>
     <!-- ec symbol + blue background -->
     <path fill-rule="nonzero" fill="#8cbce8" id="svg_5" d="m1984.25,2291.02528l1984.26,0l0,1984.25l-1984.26,0l0,-1984.25"/>
     <!-- ec symbol -->
     <path fill-rule="nonzero" fill="#ffffff" id="svg_4" d="m3540.85,3037.67528l-100.97,183.1c-39.72,68.79 -144.26,8.6 -104.58,-60.12l101.07,-183.06c39.74,-68.84 144.12,-8.57 104.48,60.08m-17.75,558.93c0,33.34 -27.02,60.24 -60.29,60.24l-211.41,0.05c-33.3,0 -60.28,-27 -60.28,-60.29c0,-33.25 26.94,-60.34 60.28,-60.34l211.41,0.05c33.31,0 60.29,26.99 60.29,60.29m-362.52,-738.96c16.65,28.85 6.78,65.71 -22.07,82.36c-28.87,16.67 -65.68,6.72 -82.31,-22.09l-105.75,-183.06c-16.65,-28.84 -6.77,-65.71 22.07,-82.36c28.79,-16.62 65.73,-6.83 82.4,22.04l105.66,183.11zm-150.24,974.55c16.66,28.85 6.77,65.71 -22.06,82.36c-28.88,16.67 -65.69,6.72 -82.32,-22.09l-105.75,-183.06c-16.65,-28.84 -6.76,-65.71 22.07,-82.36c28.8,-16.62 65.73,-6.83 82.4,22.05l105.66,183.1zm-241.49,-862.5c0,33.25 -26.96,60.34 -60.29,60.34l-211.42,-0.05c-33.29,0 -60.29,-27 -60.29,-60.29c-0.01,-33.35 27.04,-60.24 60.29,-60.24l211.4,-0.05c33.31,0 60.31,26.99 60.31,60.29m-146.85,428.75l-105.75,183.06c-16.63,28.81 -53.44,38.76 -82.31,22.09c-28.84,-16.65 -38.72,-53.51 -22.07,-82.36l105.66,-183.1c16.67,-28.88 53.61,-38.67 82.4,-22.05c28.83,16.65 38.72,53.52 22.07,82.36"/>
    </g>
   </g>
  </g>
 </g>
</svg>


</body></html>
```

Now we need a means to send the content to a PDF writer and here I use Edge but you can of course use Chrome. On Windows you may need to run that as Admin, it should only take a few seconds even on a slow 32bit win 7 device as I am currently on.

Note older windows may need `--disable-gpu` but should not now be needed since 7 is expired.

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --headless --run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw --print-to-pdf="%USERPROFILE%\desktop\OUTlogo.pdf" --print-to-pdf-no-header "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Logo.html"
```